# What simple C graphics library would you recommend?

Tags: c, graphics

I'm learning C and I would like to start graphics programming, but start it simple, without spending hours just to understand what functions will I need.

I would like something to draw pixels, squares, maybe sprites, simple stuff, like in BASIC.

I tried SDL and got overwhelmed very quickly. Same with Allegro, it's hard to get it to work on Xcode 4 and documentation is lacking.

Maybe there is some custom one? Also would be nice if it works on Mac OS.

Any book recommendations are welcome, like simple C graphics programming or game programming, whatever.

Comment: Hrmf, I was going to say SDL. Are you already familiar with graphics stuff in higher level languages?

Comment: @nmichaels nope, I'm a beginner

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If SDL is overwhelming, perhaps graphics programming is not the place to start in C. If you want to get familiar with the concepts involved in coding up graphics, try it in a higher level language like Python (with [pygame](http://pygame.org/docs/) or [pyglet](http://www.pyglet.org/).) Most high-level languages have good bindings to graphics libraries. If you really want to learn C by writing games, maybe something more text-oriented ([ncurses](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/)-based?) is appropriate.

Once you understand the fundamental idioms of graphics programming, applying them to different languages becomes much easier. You'll be able to go from pygame to SDL in C without too much extra pain beyond that inherent in going from Python to C.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go for QuickCG. [Here](http://lodev.org/cgtutor/) you can find sources and some tuts.

Answer (score 1):

The best you can use at least which is both portable and now almost an industry standard, simple graphics can be done using OpenCV. This is not limited to just drawing lines or primitives, or should I say simple graphics, I have used it for industry standard image processing products and computer vision problem solving. This will be fun if you start learning it. OpenGL is also another place to start. It might well suit what you want. Mostly related to graphics, rather than computer vision or image processing

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to investigate the Postscript language to get a feel for the stencil/paint image model. And then you could more easily get started with Cairo which implements the same model. A big advantage to the stencil/paint model is device independence. With Cairo you can perform the same drawing commands to output to a window, an in-memory pixmap, or a pdf file writer.

Answer (score 0):

"g2 graphics library" is the most simple. The programming language is C. But does not support "only" 64 bit systems (it supports 32 bit like Mac OS Mojave, and Ubuntu, have not checked up with Windows MSYS MinGw). To create User Interfaces i recommend FLTK (Fast Light Toolkit) with the UI-builder Fluid.
https://sourceforge.net/projects/g2gl/
https://www.fltk.org/software.php